# How to make spring use mysql instead of hsql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm following this guide from spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/.

Everything works as long as I use hsql, but I want to switch to mysql. The problem is that spring is always trying to start and use a hsql instance.

Following is the code:

application.properties in hello.ressources:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/xxx
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

datasource.xml in hello.ressources

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/xxx" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In my BatchConfiguration class, there is an `@Autowired` property

```
@Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;
```

Intelij shows it as connected to `datasource.xml`.

However, when I run the Application it first logs

```
o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb', username='sa'
```

which shouldn't appear and then throws an error saying:

> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PEOPLE

I have changed schema-all.sql to schema-mysql.sql and changed the code to

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;
CREATE TABLE people  (
    person_id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

In my build.gradle I have added

```
classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6'
```

to the build dependencies and changed the hsql part from the compile deps to

```
compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")
```

How can I use mysql here and disable hsql?

EDIT:

Project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWMOx.jpg

I have deleted datasource.xml.

This is build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-batch-processing'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Comment: @Jarrodroberson The question you voted to close this was about a missing class, mine is not.

Comment: Imo, this question is not a duplicate of the linked one. Sure they're both going to switch from HSQL to MySQL but this is a Spring Boot project and Boot by default configures an embedded HSQL as its Database. This question may has a duplicate but the linked question definitely is not the one

Comment: Do you have an idea how to fix this @AliDehghani

Comment: For starters, delete the `datasource.xml`. Where did you put your `application.properties`? Post your project structure and `build.gradle`.

Comment: @AliDehghani edited it in

Answer (score 0):

the steps you took should be sufficient to make spring-boot use mysql.

i see you are using spring-batch, which also comes with a hsql dependency. have you checked the logs if there is maybe a second datasource initialized? might be the hsql init you see is spring-batch trying to setup a datasource for its metadata.

also

have you tried to add

```
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
```

to application.properties?